# How to display message to user when assertEqual throws an exception?

Tags: python, unit-testing

### Question

How to display an error message to the user when my unit test raises an exception?

That is, the assert of the test not only failed, but when trying to compute whether or not the assert should pass, an exception was raised.

### Example

Suppose I have a unit test that looks like this

```
import unittest


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        ... # compute `expected`, `actual`, `helpful_info`.
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual, msg=f'The test failed. {helpful_info}')
```

where the line with the ellipsis `...` represents some unimportant logic that computes the expected and the actual variables which will be compared in the following assert, along with some helpful debug info about the context which they were computed in (which helps to understand why the test failed, if it did).

Depending on the values of `expected` and `actual`, the test might fail *without* showing me the custom message I wrote. For example, the following code:

```
import unittest
import torch

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        expected = [2,3]
        actual = torch.tensor([2,3])
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual, msg=f'This will not show: {expected}')
```

(which uses the [PyTorch library](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html)), outputs the following when ran with `python -m unittest`

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_this (test_this.TestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/juliano/test/test_this.py", line 8, in test_this
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual, msg=f'This will not show {expected}')
  File "/home/juliano/miniconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 829, in assertEqual
    assertion_func(first, second, msg=msg)
  File "/home/juliano/miniconda3/envs/pytorch_env/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 819, in _baseAssertEqual
    if not first == second:
TypeError: eq() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (list)
 * (Number other)
      didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (list)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Which, as the error message stated, happened because the `Tensor` object from PyTorch can't be compared to lists. Note that the custom message was never printed.

#### Note

This could have been circumvented by first writing an assert that checks the types of the objects that will be compared, or some other clever logic that first tests whether or not the `assertEqual` will throw an exception. I am probably not interested in this type of solution, since I would rather not try anticipating all possible causes for exceptions whenever I write an `assertEqual` statement.

Comment: The message is not displayed because it is not `assertEqual` that fails per se, it is `pytorch` that raises `TypeError` when `assertEquals` tries to use `==`. You can use `assertRaises` or check if `pytorch` comes with its own test suite, like `pandas` does.

Comment: `" I would rather not try anticipating all possible causes for exceptions whenever I write an assertEqual statement"` but isn't that the whole idea when writing unittests?

Comment: I understand that the exception is raised by `pytorch`, not by the `assertEqual`. However, in my opinion, if an exception was raised when a test was running, the test should definitely be regarded as a failure. In the case of this type of failure, I'd like to be able to print a message to the user.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, I understand your point, but I'm testing my own function, not the `assertEqual` statement.

Comment: Have you tried looking into `assertRaises` or pytorch's inhouse unittests, like I also suggested?

Comment: I'm using `assertRaises` for other tests already. From my understanding, one uses `assertRaises` to check whether the function being tested raised a specific type of exception when ran with certain inputs. I don't see how it would help in this context. I would like to test that the output of my function equals the expected output, but during the check for equality an exception is raised *by something other than the function being tested* (in this case PyTorch is the one raising it). Using an `assertRaises` in the way I'm thinking would be testing PyTorch, not my function.

Comment: Your example is about test code that is buggy (leads to comparison of non-comparable objects).  Thus, for me your question seems to be similar to "can I show some message to the user if the test code is found to be buggy?".  However, the result of executing that buggy test code is an error message, which seems appropriate for me, because that buggy test code needs fixing.  But, since you are not happy with that: Can you please give an example of what output you'd rather want to be shown?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to show a failure message when an exception is raised in assertEqual, you could just do

```
try:
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual, msg=f'The test failed. {helpful_info}')
except:
    self.assertEqual(1, 2, msg=f'An exception was raised. {helpful_info}')
```

Comment: This indeed accomplishes exactly the intended behavior, thank you. However, it seems like a workaround at best, and I guess other people reading my code (or myself, a year later) would probably frown and think for a while about why this was written like this. Hopefully someone else can provide a more pythonic (?) answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code given in question:

```
import unittest
import torch

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_this(self):
        expected = [2,3]
        actual = torch.tensor([2,3])
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual, msg=f'This will not show: {expected}')
```

Following was my output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_this (__main__.TestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/91798/PycharmProjects/API_tester/so.py", line 8, in test_this
    self.assertEqual(expected, actual, msg=f'This will not show: {expected}')
AssertionError: [2, 3] != tensor([2, 3]) : This will not show: [2, 3]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.077s
```

So, I am getting the error message, "This will not show: [2, 3]" which you wanted. Maybe it's a versioning issue.
I am using Python 3.8 and torch==1.8.1.